# problem with make ing rospack package - in mac

Tags: ros, library, tinyxml, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Guys, I'm new with ROS, I knew that it does not support OS X, but I have to run that on this system, This is OS X Yosemite 10.10.1

I did all of the installation guide for ROS hydro from the first step to the 2.1.2 Resolving Dependencies, there was some problem with dependencies which I've solved with manually doing those with "brew install ....."

After that I've completely stuck in the 2.1.3 Building the catkin Workspace  part and exactly in making rospack package,
first there was a problem with not finding the "tinyxml.h" file which I solved that with "brew install tinyxml" and "brew install tinyxml2"
and know I've stuck here.

This is the error log:

==> make -j2 -l2 in '/Users/shahriarta/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospack'
Linking CXX shared library /Users/shahriarta/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.dylib
ld: library not found for -ltinyxml
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [/Users/shahriarta/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rospack/lib/librospack.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'rospack':
Command '/Users/shahriarta/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j2 -l2' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /Users/shahriarta/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rospack && /Users/shahriarta/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j2 -l2

Command failed, exiting.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199770/problem-with-make-ing-rospack-package---in-mac/) by [shahriarta](https://answers.ros.org/users/21165/shahriarta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-12-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I encountered this error and was able to make the build succeed by replacing `-ltinyxml` with `/usr/local/lib/libtinyxml.dylib` in various `link.txt` files within `ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/`. I don't know why the linker had trouble finding that library in such a standard location.

```
grep -rl ' -ltinyxml' ./build_isolated | xargs sed -i.bak 's|-ltinyxml|/usr/local/lib/libtinyxml.dylib|g'
```

---

Originally posted by [jjclark](https://answers.ros.org/users/21411/jjclark/) with karma: 36 on 2015-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shahriarta](https://answers.ros.org/users/21165/shahriarta/) on 2015-01-19**:
Thank you so much, It solved my problem